# why a href is display inblock but the phara is in block?

Tags: css

I have learned about `display` and `float` but is like `<a>` is already inline-block like for example: http://jsfiddle.net/CDe6a/1834/

But the `<p>` elements aren't, I don't understand this; the code is:

```css
#parent {
  border: solid 5px red;
}

.child {
  border: solid 1px black;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <a href="">he</a>

  <a href="">he</a>
  <a href="">he</a>
  <p>
    a
  </p>
  <p>
    a
  </p>
</div>
```

This for example, and as you can see is inline.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, but `<p>` elements have the display value of `block` by default, `<a>` have the display value `inline`.

Comment: i thinked that all elements have display block, where can i find a list of which have display block or inline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every HTML element has a default display value depending on what type of element it is. The default display value for most elements is block or inline. `<a>` has a default of `display: inline` and `<p>` has a default of `display: block`.

You can check more here:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp